# DataSource, en el archivo application.properties

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, spring-boot

Tengo un problema, estoy tratando de conectar intellij + postgres y me pasa este problema.
[image: url attribute is not specified]

Comment: No remendamos poner imágenes. Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a nuestra [guia de preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Tienes la dependencia al driver de postgres en el POM?

Comment: Hola E. Betanzos, si lo tengo amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con `jdbc-url` (Usando el valor actual de `url`):

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://${db-host:localhost}:${db-port:5432}/postgres
```